# WP8 SDK import Service Reference with task-based operations not possible

Tags: web-services, asynchronous, visual-studio-2012, task-parallel-library, windows-phone-8

So far it seems that importing a service reference in VS2012 with "generate task-based operations" is not working. It os greyed out.

A test with a new project for WPF is working fine - I could select either task-based or async operations.

Is there a simple way on wrapping the async call in a task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a simple way on wrapping the async call in a task?

Example for `WebClient.DownloadStringCompleted`

```
public static class WebClientAsyncExtensions
{
    public static Task<string> DownloadStringTask(this WebClient client, Uri address)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
        handler = (sender, e) =>
            {
                client.DownloadStringCompleted -= handler;

                if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    tcs.SetException(e.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
                }
            };

        client.DownloadStringCompleted += handler;
        client.DownloadStringAsync(address);

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
async void DownloadExample()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    await client.DownloadStringTask(new Uri("http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266079/"));
}
```

Comment: That is true, but in .Net an async operation is not always a Task.
BeginOp() and EndOp() are usually used for async operations. In the generated WebService classes, it is done via 
void MyOp() and MyOpCompleted (event handler). Thats the old style like it was in SilverLight and WP7.x.
I need function stubs returning a Task to use the async await pattern.
Or something to dynamically create a Task from the generated functions like:
Tast.Factory.CreateFrom(BeginOp, EndOp). But this option is not available anymore for WP8 SDK.

Comment: So your question is how to implement Begin/End, as a Task? I can create a sample for that.

Comment: Updated with a example. `TaskCompletionSource<T>` is the key here.

Comment: TaskCompletionSource seems to make that all possible. But its an awfull lot to code if you have many web operations to cover.

Comment: And VS2012 already CAN create the awaitable functions stubs. Its only disabled for WP8 projects. WPF projects can switch between the two workout pattern.

Comment: Yes, but WPF and WP8 is not the same. You're not getting the full .NET API for a mobile phone.