# How can I use async/await to call a webservice?

Tags: c#, soap, windows-phone-8, wsdl

I have a [webservice](http://ychat.marpel.cz/ychat/WebService) written in [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.webservice) (php framework).

I use C# and Visual Studio 2012 to develop a WP8 application. I added a service reference to my project (Add Service Reference). So I am able to use webservice functions.

```
   client = new YChatWebService.WebServiceControllerPortTypeClient();

   client.loginCompleted += client_loginCompleted;   // this.token = e.Result;
   client.loginAsync(this.username, this.password); 

   client.getTestCompleted += client_getTestCompleted;
   client.getTestAsync(this.token);
```

function `getTestAsync` and `loginAsync` return `void` and both are asynchronous. Is it possible for the functions to return `Task<T>`? I would like to use `async`/`await` keywords in my program.

Comment: Just change the void return type to Task, then you can call await client.loginAsync(this.username, this.password);

Comment: @NickBray And then it won't work because you won't be actually returning a task that is completed at the proper time...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524395.aspx

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Assuming that loginAsync returns void, and loginCmpleted event fires when login is done, this is called the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern, or EAP.

To convert EAP to await/async, consult [Tasks and the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/tasks-and-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern/). In particular, you'll want to make use of the TaskCompletionSource to convert the event-based model to a Task-based model. Once you've got a Task-based model, you can use C# 5's sexy await feature.

Here's an example:

```
// Use LoginCompletedEventArgs, or whatever type you need out of the .loginCompleted event
// This is an extension method, and needs to be placed in a static class.
public static Task<LoginCompletedEventArgs> LoginAsyncTask(this YChatWebService.WebServiceControllerPortTypeClient client, string userName, string password) 
{ 
    var tcs = CreateSource<LoginCompletedEventArgs>(null); 
    client.loginCompleted += (sender, e) => TransferCompletion(tcs, e, () => e, null); 
    client.loginAsync(userName, password);
    return tcs.Task; 
}

private static TaskCompletionSource<T> CreateSource<T>(object state) 
{ 
    return new TaskCompletionSource<T>( 
        state, TaskCreationOptions.None); 
}

private static void TransferCompletion<T>( 
    TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e, 
    Func<T> getResult, Action unregisterHandler) 
{ 
    if (e.UserState == tcs) 
    { 
        if (e.Cancelled) tcs.TrySetCanceled(); 
        else if (e.Error != null) tcs.TrySetException(e.Error); 
        else tcs.TrySetResult(getResult()); 
        if (unregisterHandler != null) unregisterHandler();
    } 
}
```

Now that you've converted the Event-based async programming model to a Task-based one, you can now use await:

```
var client = new YChatWebService.WebServiceControllerPortTypeClient();
var login = await client.LoginAsyncTask("myUserName", "myPassword");
```

Comment: Thank you.I had to get familiar with terms such as lambda expressions, delegates..." So everything is very new for me. The compiler has a problem with "e => e" so I changed it to "() => e" and there is no option TaskCreationOptions.DetachedFromParent. What should I use instead?

Comment: TaskCreateOptions.None should be OK here. Yes, my mistake, it should be () => e, or () => e.Foo, whatever property you want to pull off there. I'll update the code.

Comment: This code won't work since user state will be null. The check in TransferCompletion (`e.UserState == tcs`) will always be false. Not sure what the best approach is here, but if tcs is passed as a third argument to `loginAsync`, it appears to work as expected.

Comment: @user3533716: That looks reasonable to me.  I believe Judah's intent was trying to ensure `loginCompleted` would properly synchronize calls and responses in the case that `LoginAsyncTask` was called more than once on the same `YChatWebService.WebServiceControllerPortTypeClient`.  It's simpler to guarantee one call per client by instantiating the client inside `LoginAsyncTask`, but Judah's approach allows the caller to construct a custom instance of `YChatWebService.WebServiceControllerPortTypeClient` (e.g., by dynamically modifying the URL).

Comment: @JudahGabrielHimango - The link you posted is dead.

Comment: Considering this was posted 8 years ago, that link lasted fairly long! I've updated the post with the correct link.

Answer (score 8):

While adding your service reference make sure you selected `Generate Task based operations` in `Advanced` section. this will create awaitable methods like `LoginAsync` returning `Task<string>`

Comment: This is using an event based model, so `FromAsync` won't help.

Comment: @Servy I used the url in the question and generated the awaitable functions automatically. Anything wrong?

Comment: I am unable to select Generate Task based operations because it is greyed out. It seems that it is disabled for  WP8 projects. See [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266079/wp8-sdk-import-service-reference-with-task-based-operations-not-possible)

Answer (score 8):

I've had to do this a couple of times over the last year and I've used both @Judah's code above and the [original example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/06/19/tasks-and-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern/) he has referenced but each time I've hit on the following problem with both: the async call works but **doesn't complete**. If I step through it I can see that it will enter the `TransferCompletion` method but the `e.UserState == tcs` will always be `false`.

It turns out that web service async methods like the OP's `loginAsync` have two signatures. The second accepts a `userState` parameter. The solution is to pass the `TaskCompletionSource<T>` object you created as this parameter. This way the `e.UserState == tcs` will return true.

In the OP, the `e.UserState == tcs` was removed to make the code work which is understandable - I was tempted too. But I believe this is there to ensure the correct event is completed.

The full code is:

```
public static Task<LoginCompletedEventArgs> RaiseInvoiceAsync(this Client client, string userName, string password)
{
    var tcs = CreateSource<LoginCompletedEventArgs>();
    LoginCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
    handler = (sender, e) => TransferCompletion(tcs, e, () => e, () => client.LoginCompleted -= handler);
    client.LoginCompleted += handler;

    try
    {
        client.LoginAsync(userName, password, tcs);
    }
    catch
    {
        client.LoginCompleted -= handler;
        tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        throw;
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Alternatively, I believe there is a `tcs.Task.AsyncState` property too that will provide the `userState`. So you could do something like:

```
if (e.UserState == taskCompletionSource || e.UserState == taskCompletionSource?.Task.AsyncState)
{
    if (e.Cancelled) taskCompletionSource.TrySetCanceled();
    else if (e.Error != null) taskCompletionSource.TrySetException(e.Error);
    else taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(getResult());
    unregisterHandler();
}
```

This was what I tried initially as it seemed a lighter approach and I could pass a Guid rather than the full TaskCompletionSource object. Stephen Cleary has a [good write-up of the AsyncState](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-2-asyncstate-and-creationoptions.html) if you're interested.

Comment: Your advice to pass along the tcs into the async call was missing link that got this working perfectly for me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

(Copied from OP, per https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150228/136378 )

**Answer:**

Following code seems to work.

```
internal static class Extension
{
    private static void TransferCompletion<T>(
        TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e, 
        Func<T> getResult)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
        }
        else if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        }
        else
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(getResult());
        }
    }

    public static Task<loginCompletedEventArgs> LoginAsyncTask(
        this YChatWebService.WebServiceControllerPortTypeClient client,
        string userName, string password)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<loginCompletedEventArgs>();
        client.loginCompleted += (s, e) => TransferCompletion(tcs, e, () => e);
        client.loginAsync(userName, password);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

I call it this way

```
client = new YChatWebService.WebServiceControllerPortTypeClient();
var login = await client.LoginAsyncTask(this.username, this.password);
```

Comment: This code may function incorrectly if a single client instance is used to make multiple simultaneous calls to `LoginAsyncTask`.  The `loginCompleted` event will fire all subscribed events at once on each completion.  This can be resolved either by using a separate client for each call (using an extension method on client is a bad idea, in this approach).  It can also be resolved by collating the callbacks with the calls via the userstate parameter (this is the approach which https://stackoverflow.com/a/14103474/18192 tries to use).

Answer (score -4):

If you want to be able to await the methods, they should return Task.  You cannot await a method that returns void.  If you want them to return a value, like int they should return `Task<int>` then the method should return int.

```
public async Task loginAsync(string username, string password) {}
```

Then you can call

```
Task t = loginAsync(username, password);
//login executing
//do something while waiting

await t; //wait for login to complete
```

Comment: He's asking *how* to do that.  He doesn't know how an event based model can return a task.

Comment: Take the same method you had and just put Task instead of void.  Then you can call await in your program.  No extra work needed.  How to use it is a different story.

Comment: You can't just change the return type of the method and be done.  The question is specifically asking how to change the implementation of the method so that it actually returns a task.  The question is asking how you create a `Task` that is completed when the data is ready, and you don't answer that.  See Judah's answer for how you actually implement it.