# C# Can't generate task based operations using service reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, service-reference

When I'm adding a service reference in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone I can't choose the option "generate task based operations". I can't even uncheck the Allow generation of asynchronous operations checkbox.

I'm using the following address: http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?wsdl

Screenshot: http://snag.gy/sLjrg.jpg

I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this option is disabled for WP8 projects.

More info here: [WP8 SDK import Service Reference with task-based operations not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266079/wp8-sdk-import-service-reference-with-task-based-operations-not-possible)