# Cannot change client settings when adding a service reference in Visual Studio for Windows phone

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Im using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone. I'm adding a service reference to a SOAP service. VS sees the service just fine and I can add the service and use it. The problem is I would like to change one of the Client settings but it seems to be disabled. I tried removing the service and adding it back but i still cant change it. Why is this disabled? is this not available with the windows phone version of VS?

Here's what the advanced settings look like:

[image: Client Settings Disabled]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Access level for generated classes**

This option is not available to Silverlight / Windows Phone applications. This is due to limitations of the Silverlight version of the **DataContractSerializer**. Fields and properties must be public to be serialized.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

*For each member of the class that returns data that you want to serialize, apply the DataMemberAttribute. You can serialize fields and properties, **provided they are publicly accessible.***

**Allow generation of asynchronous operations**

These are the only service calls allowed by Silverlight/Windows phone. See here for a way to wrap your call in a task if required:

[WP8 SDK import Service Reference with task-based operations not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266079/wp8-sdk-import-service-reference-with-task-based-operations-not-possible)